# Objective C https requests not waiting response before resuming main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, request, ios-simulator

I have an issue with my https requests (I assume it is the issue). My problem is that I have a login page that ask a php web service that I wrote to check if the user that try to log in can do so.
Https request works fine when launching the app from Xcode but after apple validation I published the app on the App Store but somehow, when I download it from the App Store the app freeze when I press the login button that starts the request...

Here is the code of my request:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://cataloguetest.tabuleo.fr/Appmobile/webServ_firstCo.php?username=%@",username];
__block BOOL endOfBlock = false;
__block NSArray *ret;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {

      NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Data received: %@", strData);
      NSError *jsonerror;
      NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonerror];
      NSString *validity =[jsonDict objectForKey:@"valid"];
      NSLog(@"get validity ok..");
      NSString *userInbase = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"usrIn"];
      NSLog(@"validity: %@",validity);
      NSLog(@"inBase: %@", userInbase);
      ret = @[validity ,userInbase];
      endOfBlock = true;
  }] resume];
while (!endOfBlock) {};
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do not transform an Asynchrone Call into a Synchrone one. Learn how yo handle properly async calls.

Comment: @Larme Ok maybe this is what I do wrong but I really need to wait until my call is finished before continuing to proceed my call.. any idea how to do it or where I can learn how to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to get the almost perfect way to do it:

```
NSString *urlCheck = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlCheck]];
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
^(NSData * _Nullable data,
NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
NSError * _Nullable error) {
  //do things with request's return
}] resume];

while(!postRequestReturned){

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate          distantFuture]];

}
NSLog(@"REQUEST resumed main thread");
```